# Can I add additional comments in generated javascript with typescript?

Tags: typescript, tsc

Working on an open-source project, I'm trying to find a way to have comments in javascript header such as "AUTO-GENERATED FILE, DO NOT MODIFY etc." ; but of course, I don't want to put those comments in typescript files, only in JS. Is there a way to do it? Maybe via some kind of tsc post-compile scripts, does it exist?

Comment: You should add JS files to .gitignore. And then publish the releases with minified JS files.

Comment: It's a possibility, that's right. However it means that people who just want to try need to install and run tsc.

Comment: Contributors have to compile before to use. Users should use compiled releases.

Comment: This could be an issue for scripts that are used to drive the build, too.  Who builds the build script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe via some kind of tsc post-compile scripts, does it exist

You can use https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-text-replace

Comment: I haven't used grunt yet, but I guess it's the best way to achieve what I want. Thanks!